# sum of two random variable

Tags: probability, random-variables

if X is a Binomial random variable (n,p), then :

```
X=Y1+Y2+Y3+Y4......Yn, where Y1,Y2....Yn are Bernoulli random variable
```

So, What exactly is this **sum** of multiply random variable means?

I know that Binomial random variable is just to repeat Bernoulli random variable n times, so the summation of two random variable means they are independent, they share the same sample space or what?

---

---

**Update:**

So, Z=X+Y, does this mean that Z=3  implies X=1 +Y=2 or X=2+Y=1 or X=0+Y=2  ?

Comment: At each realization of the experience, the $Y_j$ take some realized value ($0$ or $1$), and at each realization $X$ is the sum of those realized values. Note that $Y_1 + Y_2 + \cdots + Y_n \neq n Y_1$ since $n Y_1$ would be $n$ times the realized value of *one* of the $Y_j$, and in the sum they can take different values. Here the interpretation of the $Y_j$ is a success if $Y_j = 1$ and a failure if $Y_j = 0$. Each $Y_j$ is "associated" with one try of a "sub-experience", if you will (the "global" experience is done when you have done $n$ times the "sub-experience").

Comment: sorry, please make it more simpler to understand; I don't know what you mean by the global experience or the sub-experience.

Comment: Example : the experience consists of tossing a coin twice. Define $Y$ to be the random variable representing the number of tails you've flipped. $Y$ is a random variable because if you repeat the experience many times you may get $0$, $1$ or $2$ tails. Now, $Y$ can be seen as being the number of tails you've tossed at the first flip, plus the number of tails you've tossed at the second flip. Let $X_1$ and $X_2$ be the random variables representing the # of tails at each flip. Then $Y = X_1 + X_2$, and the distribution of $Y$ is obviously related to those of the $X_j$ ($1 \leq j \leq 2$).

Comment: Consider the example I gave you. The "global experience" is the tossing of *both* coins. The "sub-experience" is the tossing of *one* coin.

Comment: Random variables are functions and the sum of two random variables is just the sum of two functions in the usual sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The sum of a random variable means that we create a new random variable $$P = Q + R$$ such that when you draw a value from $P$ it is equal to the sum of drawing a value from $Q$ and drawing a value from $R$.

Note:

- The random variables $P$ and $Q$ can be dependent or independent.
- They do not need to share the same sample space. E.g. let $P$ = the total number of items bought on a shopping trip, $Q$ = the number of eggs bought, $R$ = the number of chickens bought, and so on. Each of the variables that's being summed can have its own range and distribution.
- You can do algebra like $P = Q + R \implies P - R = Q$, and in the case where variables are discrete if you know $P$ then this constrains $Q$ and $R$. So in your case if $Z=3$ then you can have $(X,Y)=(0,3)$ or $(1,2)$ or $(2,1)$ or $(3,0)$.

However as @Guest points out in the comments you do need to careful about algebra. If you have $P=Q+R$ and $Q=R$, e.g. $Q$ is the amount of money a shopkeeper receives from you and $R$ is the amount of money you pay the shopkeeper ($Q$ is completely dependent on $R$), then $P=2Q=2R$. But if $Q$ and $R$ just follow the same distribution as in a Binomial variable being the sum of identically distributed Bernouilli variables, you have to keep the random variables separate: $X = Y_1 + Y_2 + \ldots + Y_n$ as you wrote (this is an example where the random variables being summed are independent).